# remove whitespace from end of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove whitespace after all data in the excel table using panda in Jupiter notebook.
foreg:

```
| A header               | Another header    |
| --------               | --------------    |
| First**whitespace**    | row               |
| Second                 | row**whitespace** |
```

output:

```
| A header | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | row            |
| Second   | row            |
```

Answer (score 1):

If all columns are strings use `rstrip` in [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.rstrip())
```

Or [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) for columns in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip())
```

If possible some non strings (non object) columns is possible filter columns names:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(object).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip())
```